# Adding Input/Meta Box To Wordpress Page With Spellcheck Ability

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Within Wordpress, I am attempting to add a text box to a page where users can paste data. Within this box I simply want to give them ability to spell check the pasted text, preferably using the built in wp_editor functionality.

I've tried adding code below to the page, however all wp_editor buttons are still present including 'add media':

```
    <?php wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings = array() ); ?>
```

Thank's in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The [wp_editor()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor) function has many options. For instance, you can turn off the media insert buttons:

```
$settings = array( 'media_buttons' => false );
wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings );
```

I don't think WordPress does spellchecking. Are you sure this isn't a function of your web browser or operating system?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Shipshape. Yes, browsers and operating systems do have built in but I would like to have one on my website using the Jetpack proofreading feature. This utilizes both grammar and spelling corrections.

Comment: WordPress Visual Editor is what utilizes the Jetpack spellcheck feature.